# How can I get the value of this html input?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have:

```
$( ".cant_car" ).click(function() { 
var condiciones_more = $(this).attr('a_ref');
    <input id="plus_get" name="cart" value="1" size="4" title="Cantidad" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12">
<button  type="button" a_ref="-" class="cant_car" title="Menos">-</button>
<button  type="button" a_ref="+" class="cant_car" title="Más">+</button>
```

And Im trying to do this:

```
 var soo = $(this).closest( "#plus_get" ).val();

 alert(soo);
});
```

I get an undefined alert, how can I fix it?

The problem is I dont get the value of the input

Comment: I have already tried but it didnt solve it

Comment: You shouldn't make up custom attributes. If you need to put data into an HTML element, use `data-XXX` attributes, e.g. `data-ref="-"`.

Comment: How do you expect `.closest()` to do what you want? `.closest()` looks for the closest **containing** element that matches the selector, but `<input>` elements aren't containers.

Comment: You're missing the closing brace and parenthesis for the `.click()` function.